# How to sell software online: from freshly compiled executable to final product

Tags: software-distribution

**Suppose** I have a freshly compiled and tested 100 MB software. I want to eventually distribute it and sell it online as a product. This is a cross-platform product (done in C++).

What are the needed technical steps to achieve this? For each step, a description and an example of some software (if pertinent) would help. Also, how important is it would be helpful too.

My problem is that it is not really clear what are the stages to go through to release a software online. This list would help me a lot to know what steps I should investigate in priority.

What I am **not** talking about / interested in (because it is mainly the results I got while searching for this):

- Website building;
- Marketing & Sales;
- Continuous Integration servers;
- Steam, Mac Store, Windows Store;
- Open Source.

## Steps I identified:

- **Obfuscate:** not sure about this one;
- **Licensing System:** activation code system integrated in the software directly (See Digital River, SafeNet, Reprise, Flexera);
- **Installers:** MSI for Windows (see Wix), DMG for mac;
- **Code Signing:** ensures that your users do not get warnings (Verisign, GlobalSign...)
- **Free Trial Distribution:** putting the installers on our own site is risky because of bandwidth and lags. Your users should be able to download a free trial quickly wherever they are. So a CDN would help (AWS CloudFront).
- **Auto Update System:** notifiy the users, download and install new versions (Omaha);
- **Activation:** this allows the user to activate the product online or directly from within the product;

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because software sales are off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @PlatinumAzure: this has nothing to do with sales. I want to talk about licensing systems, obfuscation, auto update systems. Create a checklist of each steps BEFORE actual sales.

Answer (score 2):

I think that these two steps are the missing pieces in your list:

- Write documentation (in your case PDF/RTF/HTML, or online tutorial)
- Integrate a payment provider that will accept the payment on behalf of you

With the above two steps you should be ready to go.

There are some books that I can recommend you (they are 10 year old now, but you see shareware/try before you buy/ software is an old thing - nowadays people tend to write web apps or mobile mostly):

http://www.alibris.com/From-Program-to-Product-Turning-Your-Code-Into-a-Saleable-Product-Rocky-Smolin/book/10572213?matches=50

http://www.alibris.com/Micro-Isv-From-Vision-to-Reality-Bob-Walsh/book/9122742?matches=37